# Primefaces resize dialog with animation

Tags: animation, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

Is it possible to use animation such as "slide" to make primefaces dialog larger on some user event as "checkBox-Button click"?

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/effect.xhtml

E.g.:

Before:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ OpenBtn                +
+                        +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++

-->


+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ ClickedOpenBtn                +
+                               +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

-->

After:

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ ClickedOpenBtn    Some new Text  +
+                                  +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```